# Docker deployment of flask app with Celery and Redis in AWS, DB in AWS RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, flask, docker-compose

I need to deploy a Flask app with Celery and Redis to Amazon AWS. I'm used to work with  AWS Lightsail and this will be my option.

By the other side I must( as per company policy) deploy my Postgres DB  to AWS RDS

Im planing to use Dockers with  Ngix, Unicorn  in the AWS Lightsail to deploy the app that as I said uses Celery and Redis. So all this will be in the docker in Lightsail

By the other side the DB will be in RDS without using docker

What I want with this approach is a quick deployment of changes and upgrades to the app .

What I want to know is this :

1-Is this a good approach to production, that will help me in quick deployments ?
2-Does anybody know of some examples of docker-compose files that could help me with this ?
3-Could someone please let me know some limitation in this approach and 
4-Is Lightsail a good  option in AWS for a Docker deployment of flask apps as the one described here  ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because planning your whole system architecture is beyond the focus of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I asked this question, was looking for some examples of easy deployment of medium complexity apps to AWS. The app itself used Celery Redis and Amazon AWS RDS postgress DB. The deployment to Amazon Lightsail was pretty simple after I look a video in you tube from an Amazon Engineer. I basically created the container in my local laptop , used an initial script while deploying an OS only Ubuntu instance and that scrip loaded a daemon so Ubuntu "system" could daemonize my Docker deployment when restarting. I created 3 videos in you tube where I explained everything.

If someone needs help with this see the videos at:

1. Dockerize Flask API ,NGINX, GUNICORN, CELERY,REDIS to Amazon AWS
   Part1:3
2. Dockerize Flask API ,NGINX, GUNICORN, CELERY,REDIS to Amazon
   AWS Part2:3
3. Dockerize Flask API ,NGINX, GUNICORN, CELERY,REDIS to
   Amazon AWS Part3:3

Links below:

- [Part1:3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7ld4YjvuOs&list=LLWDqRaG0iRTqJKtfeFQsLng&index=3)
- [Part2:3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXyL2_zJXCg&index=2&list=LLWDqRaG0iRTqJKtfeFQsLng)
- [Part3:3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inVUmz4Dwv4&list=LLWDqRaG0iRTqJKtfeFQsLng&index=3)